# Bash environment variable to include path of c libraries

Tags: bash, build

I built a C library (compiled from source) below my home folder and now I have to build a new package that depends on that library. When running the configure script I get the error
`configure: error: The required <package> library was not found.`

Is there an environment variable  I can edit to make my script search the library's path?

I already tried `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Many libraries use pkg-config, so tell it where to find your locally installed `.pc` files:

  ```
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$LOCAL/lib/pkgconfig:$LOCAL/share/pkgconfig"
  ```

  (The system-wide directories will be included automatically.)

  Sometimes a library-specific command is used instead of the generic *pkg-config*; for example, *krb5-config*. In this case, point to your `bin` directory:

  ```
  export PATH="$LOCAL/bin:$PATH"
  ```
- If pkg-config is not used, you will have to manually point the compiler and linker to the right place.

  ```
  export CFLAGS="-I$LOCAL/include"     # for the C compiler
  export CXXFLAGS="-I$LOCAL/include"   # for the C++ compiler
  export LDFLAGS="-L$LOCAL/lib"        # for the linker
  ```
- `./configure --help` will usually list a series of `--with-feature=...` options, which allow specifying locations of each library separately.

  Often, `./configure --help` will also list environment variables for each library (such as `CURL_CFLAGS` and `CURL_LIBS`); look for "C compiler flags" or "linker flags" in the help text.

  If you often need more than one custom library, this will quickly become inconvenient; you should instead specify pkg-config path and cflags for all libraries at once.
- You *may* also need to point the loader to your library location while compiling. For Linux, it would be:

  ```
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LOCAL/lib"
  ```

  This shouldn't be necessary when *running* compiled programs; the linker will have added the correct paths to the compiled binary itself (look for "Library rpath" in `readelf -d yourprogram` if you want to check).

  For Mac OS X, setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` should have a similar effect; `otool` can be used for inspecting applications.

---

In all examples above, `$LOCAL` will be the prefix you used when installing libraries; for example, if you did `./configure --prefix ~/usr`, then use ~/usr here.

Comment: +1 for all the useful information. I got it to work before seeing your answer but I had to go in and edit the configure script.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed the library, you'll need to pass its include path to your configure script, similar to what is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958904/how-to-specify-include-directory-for-configure-script).

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` would be used after you get it compiled, so you can find the library at runtime.